# SVG - circles with stroke-width are not filled in chrome

Tags: css, svg, geometry

I am trying draw circles in SVG with different results in chrome/opera and IE/firefox.

Attached image shows how are the circles drawn in chrome (left) and in firefox (right).
[image]
.

```
<svg>
  <style>
    .circle { fill: #00FF00; stroke: #00FF00; stroke-width: 18px; }
  </style>
  <circle class="circle" cy="45" cx="390" r="1" />
</svg>
```

Is there any way how to force chrome to fill the circles like firefox?

*NOTE: I know that correct solutions lies in "r" attribute, but I want to draw circles width "stroke-width" attribute, because it can be set by css. In my app, there is a lot of circles and I need to change their size and change CSS attribute is much more faster than change "r" attribute of each circle in loop.*

Comment: having just taken a quick look on the w3c document, I would suggest that chrome is actually drawing the circle correctly. By setting `r='1'` as you have done, that will give the 1px radius for the `fill` http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/shapes.html#CircleElement

Comment: Interesting. Chrome is doing the fill right but the stroke wrong?

Comment: No. This seems to be a Chrome bug.  It shouldn't look like that.  FF is right.  You should consider reporting this bug at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/  Check that it isn't already report though.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a bug, because opera does the same as chrome. FF and IE have circles filled, Opera and chrome don't.

Comment: It looks to be a bug indeed: see the filed issue https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=239860 and a test fiddle https://fiddle.skia.org/c/022251ed97b2c2e6c545c603035a271f -- both refer to be an underlying engine issue, as far as I get it.

Comment: Opera and Chrome share the same Blink rendering engine. Any issue will affect both. FF and IE are correctly drawing the question markup.

Answer (score 0):

It's not good even in Firefox, albeit in a different way, e.g. a partial arc:

```
<svg width="200" height="200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <style>
        path {
            fill: green;
            stroke: green;
            stroke-width: 128;
            stroke-opacity: 0.5;
            stroke: url(#MyGradient);
        }
    </style>
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="MyGradient">
            <stop offset="25%" stop-color="red"></stop>
            <stop offset="75%" stop-color="blue"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <path d="M84,62 a21,21 0 1,0 28,0"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Seems like a different issue (rather than an answer to the question). Best report it [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core&component=SVG)

Answer (score -1):

You also can set the fill value via CSS. If you want to have a filled circle, you should use that.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <circle class="circle" cy="45" cx="390" r="18" fill="#00FF00" />
    <circle class="circle" cy="85" cx="390" r="18" fill="none" stroke="#00FF00" stroke-width="1px" />
</svg>
```

Displays the same as:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <style>
        .circle {
            fill: #00FF00;
            stroke: #00FF00;
            stroke-width: 0;
        }
        .circle-stroke {
            fill: none;
            stroke-width: 1px;
        }
    </style>
    <circle class="circle" cy="45" cx="390" r="18" />
    <circle class="circle circle-stroke" cy="85" cx="390" r="18" />
</svg>
```

You could even switch between the two states by just adding and removing the class `.circle-stroke` in the second example.

Comment: This looks like a solution, but unfortunatelly not for me. Like I wrote, there is a lot of circles in my app, so for me it is unacceptable to create for each circle two objects. My circles can have about 10 states, so it would mean 10x more objects in my case.

Comment: @Sylar ??? You only need one circle each – you just need to manipulate the CSS class (either while generating the SVG or on the client side using JS)

Comment: @feeela: the issue is vice versa, try your examle with `.circle-stroke {stroke-width: 101}` -- it's really not how it should look like and it's a bug caused by the stroke intersecting itself and effectively substracting itself from the inside